# DGRid showing Selected but no Bookmark

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

Just found a weirdness with D5 and/or Zeos. I have a TDBgrid and DataSet.

I have a "Delete" function to delete selected Rows of the DBGrid.

If I Ctlr-Left-click to select Row (or Rows) it all works fine, but...

if I use the Vertical Scrollbar slider to move to the top of the DataSet then it shows the first Row in the select color.

If do **not** click the top line, (it already looks selected) then click "Delete" it crashes. Stepping through the code, at the first line SelectedRows.Count displays "1" but then at the Bookmark line I get a "Bookmark not found error" If I first click on the already selected Row after using the slider, then this does not crash.

```
for i:=0 to dbgridAddr.SelectedRows.Count-1 do
begin
  dbgridAddr.DataSource.DataSet.GotoBookmark(pointer(dbgridAddr.SelectedRows.Items[i]));
```

How can I fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: It seems you're doing something really ugly with casts there. Bookmarks really are pointers, and maybe dbGrid.SelectedRows is a valid thing to cast to pointers, but doing that during event handling might not be atomic or safe.

Comment: @warren Ugly casts or not, that comes straight from the Delphi Help examples ! Cain't be too ugly. :)

Comment: Yeah I guess I forgot how gross Bookmarks in Datasets really are.

Comment: @user2220358: Have you seen the update in my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to answer I guess, but maybe someone else can find it useful. The problem is that as you click within the boundaries of a DbGrid, a row shows up as selected even though it is not .

Add this to the OnDrawColumnCell event handler of your DBGrid:

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect; 
                     DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState); 
begin  
    // Only highlight the row if it is actually selected
    if TDBGrid(Sender).SelectedRows.CurrentRowSelected  then
    begin
      TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Brush.Color := clHighlight;
      TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Font.Style := Font.Style + [fsBold];
      TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Font.Color := clHighlightText;
    end
    else
    begin
      TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Brush.Color := clBtnFace;
      TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Font.Style := Font.Style - [fsBold];
      TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Font.Color := clWindowText;
    end;  
    // Commit drawing
    TDBGrid(Sender).DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect, DataCol, Column, State);

end;
```

Add a block like this if you want to be able to see the cursor position in the grid when using the arrow keys

```
    else if (gdSelected in State) then
    begin
      TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Brush.Color := clBtnFace;
      TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Font.Style := Font.Style + [fsBold];
      TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Font.Color := clWindowText;
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Delphi 5:

You wrote:

`if I use the Vertical Scrollbar slider to move to the top of the DataSet then it shows the first Row in the select color.`

*Even if it looks that way. This does not mean that it is also evaluated as marked.*

You can test it with:

```
if dbgridAddr.SelectedRows.CurrentRowSelected then
      ShowMessage('selected') else
      ShowMessage('NOT selected');
```

#### Description

Position markers are not automatically removed from the list when records are deleted from the dataset.

It follows that some position markers **may be invalid**.

`dbgridAddr.SelectedRows.Refresh;`

Refresh to make sure that the list contains only valid entries.

Refresh trying to locate all records in the dataset that appear as a position marker in the Items property array.

All position marker for which there is no equivalent in the amount of data will be deleted.

If the position marker is invalid , Refresh returns a value of `True` and makes the DBGrid-object invalid so that a redraw is triggered, in which case all invalid records are deleted.

If all the position marker in the list should be valid, Refresh returns a value of `False`.

**Never delete items ​​from lists with this construction.**

```
for i:=0 to whatEver.Count-1 do  
    whatEver.delete(i);
```

e.g. Consider a list with 10 items on.

whatEver = `0 .. 9`

If we now in the "for loop" with `i = 1` do `whatEver.delete(i);`,

With this we delete the second item.

Now `whatEver` is only `0 .. 8` .

The loop is initialized to run through `0 to 9`. Now you can understand if `i = 9` then with `whatEver.delete(i);` attempts to access `whatEver` outside of `0 .. 8`
This leads to errors.

Another example.

You delete incorrect records.

We will assume.
**Before** the lopp you've identified the following items (data record) - number to delete.

`#3 , #6 , #8`

```
for i:=0 to whatEver.Count-1 do  
    if (i=3) OR (i=6) OR (i=8) then whatEver.delete(i);
```

if `i=3` then following is executed `whatEver.delete(3);`

afterwards

row 4 is now row 3
row 5 is now row 4
row 6 is now row 5
and so on

now with

```
if... OR (i=6) then whatEver.delete(6);
```

you delete the wrong item, the previous row 7 !

Also the bookmark pointer refers to #6, without refresh.

Please don't post now `it is better to compare the content`.

```
for i:=0 to whatEver.Count-1 do  
    if (whatEver[i] = 'blue') OR (whatEver[i] = 'green') OR (whatEver[i] = 'red')
       then whatEver.delete(i);
```

`I know that, it's just an example to show what happens when you delete items from the sequence out.`

**Do it better this way**:

```
for i:= whatEver.Count-1 downto 0 do
    whatEver.delete(i);
```

So that it is started from the end with the delete. Lower items keep their validity.

**Edit:**

I don't know what event of DBGrid you are using?

To test that there is no selection, only with a scroll.

Close your App und restart, do nothing only scroll the DBGrid.
*Do not click into the DBGrid !!*
Then press your testbutton.

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

if DBGrid1.SelectedRows.CurrentRowSelected then
  begin
     ShowMessage('selected');
  end else begin
     if DBGrid1.SelectedRows.Count>0 then
        ShowMessage('             CurrentRow NOT selected'+#13#10+
                    'A part in your code must have select another row.')
     else
        ShowMessage('NOT selected');
  end;
end;
```

[image]

Comment: @miskito thanks for the detailed reply, but I am not deleting or changing the dataset in anyway at that stage I am just using the scroll bar slider to move the **view** of the dataset to show the first item at the top and it automatically gets Visually selected. The Test you describe is exactly the same as I mentioned in the OP when stepping through in debug mode. The "SelectedRows.Count shows as "1" which is the highlighted first row. BUT, the Bookmark is not set even though it is highlighted/Selected.